# network of two Host-only VMware

Tags: vmware-workstation

I try to connect two VMware (with WinXP) on/inside on host computer(with windows 7). The configurations are:

```
VM1: network adapter - host-only with ip address: 192.168.10.50
VM2: network adapter - host-only with ip address: 192.168.10.100

Host computer: Property of VMnet1 192.168.10.250
```

Virtual Network Editor; VMnet1 - hostonly, connect a host virtual adapter t this network, DHCP is deactivated.

Finally what i get is:

in VM1:

```
both ping 192.168.10.100 and ping 192.168.10.250 work,
```

in VM2:

```
only ping 192.168.10.250 works, but ping 192.168.10.50 not works
```

in Host computer

```
only ping 192.168.10.100 works, but ping 192.168.10.50 not works
```

What's the problem with VM2. Which configuration should i check?

BTW, the version of my VMware Workstation is 7.

Answer (score 1):

Since both the hosts and guests are to be on the same subnetwork, you should be using "bridged" networking configuration here and all devices will be able to communicate if they're using the same network and subnet mask.